# Iterate over list without modifying it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm fairly new to c#, so I'm a little bewildered by this. I have a function in a `for` loop, which references one array and returns another, but the array it's taking in is getting modified too. Do I need to clone the array each time before passing it in?

```
for (int floor = 0; floor < numberOfFloors; ++floor)
{
    // takes in linePoints, does some calculations and returns a new list
    List<Vector3> floorLinePoints = processFloorSetbacks(linePoints); 
}
```

The original linePoints array is modified on each iteration - is it meant to do that?

Comment: if you modify each linepoint in processFloorSetbacks the changes will stay there regardless, you will need to recreate aech line point with the modifications you want, or clone them. i.e not edit the one passed in

Comment: Very unclear what kind of help you are looking for. If you don't want to modify incoming data than just  don't modify incoming data...You may want to provide [MCVE] that shows your problem...

Comment: ...how is that "very unclear"? It's pretty clear I don't want the original array modified, and was asking if I needed to clone it each time to achieve this.

Comment: Just iterating and *reading* values from a `List` or array will not modify it. Ergo your code must be writing to it somewhere, but we don't know where since this is not a [mcve]

Comment: Okay okay, you don't need to send me the link again, I thought that'd be enough context. @Saruman if you'd like to resubmit your comment as an answer I'll give it a tick? It's pretty much the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you modify each `linepoint` in `processFloorSetbacks` the changes will stay there regardless, you will need to recreate each `linePoint` with the modifications you want, or clone them to recreate the list. i.e not edit the one passed in.

You could potentially clone the list by selecting into a new list at the start of your `processFloorSetbacks` method and using the cloned list to do your modifications

```
var clonedList = linePoints.Select(x => new Vector3
{
     SomeValue = x.SomeValue,
     SomeOtherValue = X.SomeOtherValue,
     // and so on
}
```

Or if it might be as simple as passing in some initial arguments to its constructor (i'm not sure)

```
var clonedList = linePoints.Select(x => new Vector3( x.SomeValue, x.SomeOtherValue));
```

Note : As i'm not sure of the unity 3 Structure Vector3, so i'm not sure how you would go about cloning them, maybe this should be other question for the Unity3d crew.

Comment: `UnityEngine.Vector3` is actually a `struct` so doing `linePoints.Select(x => x)` is enough to clone the objects.

Comment: @MitchEff awesome comment by Scott